# Transition css hover effects on image

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I need to do a task where I have an image, this image is being covered in some color fade, and when I hover on image - fade dissapears (the example is https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/forty/ ). I did it, but I also have to do a transition so that disappearing of fade will be slower for 2 seconds. I tried to put transition property everywhere and I failed. Any help, please?

```css
.photo-text.one {
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("https://i2.wp.com/www.thehopelesshousewife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Christmas-No-Bake-Nachos-576x409.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  height: 409px;
  position: relative;
  width: 576px;
}

.img-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #6fc3df;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.photo-text.one:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("https://i2.wp.com/www.thehopelesshousewife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Christmas-No-Bake-Nachos-576x409.jpg") no-repeat center top;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-text one">
  <div class="img-overlay"></div>
  <h2 class="text">fffff</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this block of code :

```
.photo-text.one:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("https://i2.wp.com/www.thehopelesshousewife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Christmas-No-Bake-Nachos-576x409.jpg") no-repeat center top;
}
```

You can simplify by simply hiding the overlay by modifying its opacity to 0 with the transition of opacity and the duration you need:

```
.photo-text.one:hover > .img-overlay{
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```css
.photo-text.one {
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("https://i2.wp.com/www.thehopelesshousewife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Christmas-No-Bake-Nachos-576x409.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  height: 409px;
  position: relative;
  width: 576px;
}

.img-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #6fc3df;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.photo-text.one:hover > .img-overlay{
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-text one">
  <div class="img-overlay"></div>
  <h2 class="text">fffff</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I need! Thanks a lot

Comment: @AndyG No problem, don't forge to rate or mark the answer if you found it helpful. Cheers :)

Comment: I have one more question: when I hover on text - nothing happens, overlay (blue color) doesn't disappear. what should I add?

Comment: It is disappearing, what are you talking about? Hover over the fffff and the blue overlay disappears/

Answer (score 0):

You could just `hover` over the `.img-overlay`, but since you also want to have the same effect when *hovering* over the text, leave it as it is and just replace the `:after` *pseudo-element* (don't need it) with the `> .img-overlay`, set its `opacity` to `0` and apply the `transition` *property* as desired:

```css
.photo-text.one {
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("https://i2.wp.com/www.thehopelesshousewife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Christmas-No-Bake-Nachos-576x409.jpg") no-repeat center top;
  height: 409px;
  position: relative;
  width: 576px;
  max-width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute; /* needs to be on the child since the relative position is on the parent */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #6fc3df;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 2s linear; /* optional / when "unhovering" */
}

/* added */
.photo-text.one:hover > .img-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s linear; /* can also try other values such as "ease", "ease-out" etc. */
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 150px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-text one">
  <div class="img-overlay"></div>
  <h2 class="text">fffff</h2>
</div>
```